# VBA rounddown cashier program

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at VBA and I am trying to create a program that gives the amount of 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 and 1 after the user enters how much the product cost and how much he paid with. It works, however if the user pay 30 for the product with 200, then the program gives back 2 x 100, as change. Where it should only be 1 x hundred, 1 x fifty and 1 x 20. Can someone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
Dim userinput As Integer
Dim paid As Integer

Dim hundra100 As Integer
Dim femtio50 As Integer
Dim tjugo20 As Integer
Dim tio10 As Integer
Dim fem5 As Integer
Dim ett1 As Integer

userinput = InputBox("How much did the products cost?", "Cost")
paid = InputBox("How much did you pay with?", "Paid")

exchange = paid - userinput

hundra100 = exchange / 100
kvarHundra = exchange Mod 100

femtio50 = kvarHundra / 50
kvarFemtio = kvarHundra Mod 50

tjugo20 = kvarFemtio / 20
kvarTjugo = kvarFemtio Mod 20

tio10 = kvarTjugo / 10
kvarTio = kvarTjugo Mod 10

fem5 = kvarTio / 5
kvarFem = kvarTio Mod 5

ett1 = kvarFem / 1

MsgBox ("Your change is: " & exchange & vbNewLine & "100: " & hundra100 & vbNewLine & "50: " & femtio50 & vbNewLine _
& "20: " & tjugo20 & vbNewLine & "10: " & tio10 & vbNewLine & "5: " & fem5 & vbNewLine & "1: " & ett1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is none of the answers correct?

Answer (score 0):

exchange = paid - userinput 
get the positive value by change it to this 
exchange = userinput - paid 
rounddown every variable for hundra100, femtio50, and others by using Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown function 
e.g.: Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(hundra100, 0)
`hundra100  = exchange / 100`
`hundra100  = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(hundra100, 0)`
`kvarHundra = exchange Mod 100`
`Range("A2").Value = hundra100`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rounding as William suggests you can use int() to truncate the float.

```
Sub ttt()
    Dim userinput As Integer
    Dim paid As Integer

    Dim hundra100 As Integer
    Dim femtio50 As Integer
    Dim tjugo20 As Integer
    Dim tio10 As Integer
    Dim fem5 As Integer
    Dim ett1 As Integer

    userinput = InputBox("How much did the products cost?", "Cost")
    paid = InputBox("How much did you pay with?", "Paid")

    exchange = paid - userinput

    hundra100 = Int(exchange / 100)
    kvarHundra = exchange Mod 100

    femtio50 = Int(kvarHundra / 50)
    kvarFemtio = kvarHundra Mod 50

    tjugo20 = Int(kvarFemtio / 20)
    kvarTjugo = kvarFemtio Mod 20

    tio10 = Int(kvarTjugo / 10)
    kvarTio = kvarTjugo Mod 10

    fem5 = Int(kvarTio / 5)
    kvarFem = kvarTio Mod 5

    ett1 = kvarFem / 1

    MsgBox ("Your change is: " & exchange & vbNewLine & "100: " & hundra100 & vbNewLine & "50: " & femtio50 & vbNewLine _
    & "20: " & tjugo20 & vbNewLine & "10: " & tio10 & vbNewLine & "5: " & fem5 & vbNewLine & "1: " & ett1)
End Sub
```

The problem with the code is that all your variables are declared as integers but in your calculation the number becomes a float so it rounds the number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped and worked out fine! Thanks again!

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted my answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Cam ? When people see that you don't accept people's answers they will not help you.